# Sub Directorys with owssvr.dll in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Im trying to extend an existing program to include sub directorys, It gets the information it needs from 
/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={ListID}&XMLDATA=TRUE

and it shows sub directoys in its output.

How can i then repeat the same thing for the subdirectory ?  It works fine for all items in the root folder, I just cant "travel" further

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to retrieve the contents of the subdirectory by adding the RootFolder querystring parameter. `RootFolder=/SiteName/Subsite/Lists/ListName/FolderName`. I got the clue from hovering over the foldername in the SP view.